# Put Downloaded Emails Back to POP3 Server

Tags: upload, pop3, thunderbird, webmail

How can I put my downloaded emails back to my POP3 server? I want it to appear like how it was sent originally. I made a mistake of setting thunderbird to delete my server-side emails and keep only the local one. Now I need to re-upload it back to my web mail. How do I go about doing such?

NOTE:
The Mailredirect Extension is not compatible with my current ThunderBird so I don't think that trick will be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POP3 protocol has no provisions for uploading messages. You could use IMAP to upload them, if the server supports it, or just re-submit the messages to the mailserver via SMTP (this will add more Received: lines, and pass through any spam filtering or the like again, however)

Comment: Hmm how would I go about using IMAP to upload it? I'm using Windows Live Mail btw.

Comment: Hm? Is this a programming question, or a support question? If the latter, it should probably be moved to superuser, where people might be able to give more specific advice...